# Как в цикле узнать дистанции

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, for

Задача,- узнать дистанции до точки, от нескольких "пунктов отправления". Есть,- массив координат точек А которые в цикле и перебираются, и неизменная точка Б.
Пытаюсь делать таким образом:

```js
for (var i = 0, l = yLenght; i < l; i++) {//yLenght=кол-во точек А в массиве
            // Берем путевые точки
            var referencePoints = multiRoute.model.getReferencePoints();
            // Задаем путевым точкам свои координаты
            referencePoints[0] = Bazis;//неизменная точка Б
            // и координата из массива, искомая по индексу i
            referencePoints[1] = ybc[i].geometry.getCoordinates();
            // Устанавливаем точки в модель мультимаршрута
            multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints(referencePoints);
            // Дожидаемся обновления данных маршрута
            multiRoute.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
                // Получение ссылки на активный маршрут.
                var activeRoute = multiRoute.getActiveRoute();
                // Получаем дистанцию и пишем ее в перменную
                var length = activeRoute.properties.get("distance").value;
                // Вывод информации о маршруте.
                 console.log("Длина маршрута " + i + " = "+ length + 
                 "координаты А = " + referencePoints[1]);
              
            });
        }
```

Проблема в том, что в итоге выводит информацию от первой точки в массиве, когда нужно от всех(их 2-3).

Примеров достаточно похожих чтобы разобраться не нашел, и к сожалению не достаточно силен в JS, поэтому предполагаю что ошибка простая, но очень долго не могу ее выявить, поэтому надеюсь поможет не только мне, но и тем кто потом прочтет. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Давным давно собирала такой пример, кажется, похожая задача: https://jsfiddle.net/r4s4Lj39/2/ 
Только обратите внимание, что такие задачи могут быстро выесть дневной лимит по ключу или нарушать условия использования ещё как-то.

Comment: Так и не выяснил в чем была проблема, но именно пример  Reni помог решить мою проблему. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я не проверял, но кажется что Вы в цикле вызвали

```
 multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints(referencePoints);
```

а после всего этого n раз сработал обработчик `requestsuccess` вызвал

```
 var activeRoute = multiRoute.getActiveRoute();
```

на момент вызова там значение с последней итерации цикла

Comment: Вызов происходит после обновления данных маршрута. И если меняю activeRoute на var length = multiRoute.getRoutes().get(0).properties.get("distance").value; Результат получается тот-же.